# problem installing flutter on Mac -- cmdline-tools component is missing

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to install flutter on Mac. flutter doctor reports:

```
 ✗ cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
  

Can anyone help?  Thanks in advance.

kenn

I read the documentation and tried

cmdline-tools;latest"

no success.   much frustration.
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this simple steps to resolve this error

1. Open Android Studio
2. Open SDK manager
   [image]
3. Select `Android SDK` on left side panel and `SDK Tool` in tabs as shown in image . Select `Android SDK Command-Line Tools` and tap on `Apply` button . In my case , it is already installed
   [image]
4. after install success , try again with `flutter doctor -v` and this issue must be resolved